# Different result writing to binary file with python and matlab

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, binaryfiles

I am attempting to convert a matlab script to python. The script involves writing data to a binary file. I have noticed differences between the files, specifically when writing matrices/numpy arrays. When writing other variable types (int, string etc) the files are identical as desired.

Matlab code:

```
fid = fopen("test2.txt", "wb");
a = [[1 2];[3 4]];
fwrite(fid, a, "float64");
fclose(fid);
```

Matlab result (as shown by notepad):

<s>ð?      @       @      @</s>

[image: matlab result]

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
with open("test2.txt", "wb") as fid:
    a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
    fid.write(a.astype("float64"))
    # a.astype("float64").tofile(fid) # also doesn't give correct result
```

Python result (as shown by notepad):

<s>ð?       @      @      @</s>

[image: python result]

Comment: The results you posted look identical to me, can you point out the difference?

Comment: @BatWannaBe Looks like SO strips the characters (the squares) which show the difference. Screenshots have been added which show the difference.

Comment: Your NumPy and MATLAB matrices are not the same, they are transposed versions of each other. Consequently they are written to file in a different order.

Comment: Note also that in MATlAB, `a = [[1 2];[3 4]];` has a lot of redundant brackets, it is better to write `a = [1 2; 3 4];`.

Comment: I don't think they are transposed versions of each other.  To confirm this, a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]; and a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]) give the same size/shape but show differences in the binary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters still look very similar due to how Notepad is attempting to read integers as text, but I think it gave enough of a hint. For easier typing, let's call Matlab's text `d? [@ _@ [@` and Python's text `d? _@ [@ [@`.

Computer memory is linear, so all multidimensional arrays are actually stored as 1D arrays. What you're seeing is NumPy arrays being C order (by default) versus Matlab matrices being Fortran order (by default). This order is how multidimensional arrays are flattened to 1D arrays in memory.

```
matrix   notepad text
1  2     d?  _@               
3  4     [@  [@

Matlab Fortran order goes by columns
 1  3  2  4
d? [@ _@ [@

NumPy C order goes by rows
 1  2  3  4
d? _@ [@ [@
```

Since you're converting code between MATLAB and Python, you should be very aware of array orders being different. Iteration is faster when you don't jump around in memory, so nested for-loops may have to be reordered. It won't make much of a difference for vectorized code `someScalar * myArray` because it's handled for you. NumPy does provide functions and optional arguments to create Fortran order arrays `numpy.asfortranarray(), ndarray.copy(order = 'F')` and to check the order `ndarray.flags.f_contiguous, ndarray.flags.c_contiguous`, but coding with that is still tougher because C order is the default.

Comment: I was able to achieve the correct output using ``a.T.astype("float64").tofile(fid)``, but ``fid.write(a.T.astype("float64")`` causes a ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous

Comment: I'm not sure if using Python's `open` to save binary files is the way to go here. I'm sure you can figure out how to make it work, but there's a reason NumPy provides `numpy.save`/`.npy` files and MATLAB provides `save`/`.mat` files. I don't use MATLAB so I can't tell you if MATLAB has something similar, but SciPy, which builds on NumPy, actually provides a way to work with `.mat` files: `scipy.io.savemat, scipy.io.loadmat, scipy.io.whosmat`

Comment: The MATLAB script I am converting is used to create Finite Element models files (with a prescriptive format/data layout), so working in .mat or .npy isn't possible. With your explanation, I have been able to solve my issue.